# How add Multiple selection Listbox to a cell in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, drop-down-menu

How do I add a Multiple selection list to an Excel spredsheet in each cell of one column. I need to be able to read the selected values in c#.

Looking for a managed code solution. **CANNOT USE INTEROP**

Anything that allows a multiple selection and the aability to read using OLEDB, currently using a listbox.

WE can only use ADO.NET & C#

The dropdown list must appear in each row and it's vaule should be read from OLEDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VSTO to create an Excel worksheet, add a ListBox, set it's SelectionMode to "MultiSimple" or MultiExtended". You can the write the code behind to create it however you like - on all rows, getting data from OLEDB, etc.

Comment: Then you cannot do what you are asking for. AT ALL.

Comment: Is it not achievable using data validation?